# How to analyze an RC circuit with triangle wave voltage input?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, current, resistors, analog

I have the following circuit below where I am trying to measure the current through R5. I have parasitic components C1, C2, C3, C4, R2, R3 and R4. I also intentionally added series resistance R1 and R5. I have a 10V peak to peak, 1kHz, triangle wave on the input of the circuit. Both C3 and R3 will vary and are the "sensors" or inputs for this circuit. How can i find the total current through R5 as a function of C3 and R3 at various points in time?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1VSQE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Without accounting for any of the parasitic, and assuming that the voltage drop across R1 and R5 is minimal, the output current is about

\$I_{R5} = C_p * \frac{dV_1}{dt} = 50pF * 40\frac{kV}{s} = 2uA\$

I am unsure of how to account for the parasitic of the circuit.

I wanted to combine each element to get total impedance of the circuit, then i could find the current through R1 and work my way through the circuit until i have all the values i need. Ideally i would have used phasor analysis to find the output current and phase but this only applies to sine waves. My next thought was that the triangle wave can be described as shown [here](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/Book%3A_AC_Electrical_Circuit_Analysis%3A_A_Practical_Approach_(Fiore)/01%3A_Fundamentals/1.3%3A_Basic_Fourier_Analysis) using the Fourier series

[image: v(t)=∑n=1∞1/(2n−1)2cos((2n−1)2πft)]

If i used the Fourier series, I could use phasor analysis to find the answer where the impedance of each capacitor would be the sum of all odd multiples of the original frequency, but this now becomes an approximation as i would need to limit the number or harmonics used.

Is there another or better way of finding this answer? I need an equation to use and cannot rely on a simulation to find the answer.

**EDIT:**

I apologize for any confusion. Yes I am looking to characterize the device composed of C3 and R3. I need a formula specifically because the current that passed through R5 actually goes into an inverting op amp with a virtual ground. The signal is then amplified and passed into an ADC. We then need to determine the values for C3 and R3 and report the data. Unfortunately, we are required to use a triangle wave as the input regardless of whether or not that's the most ideal waveform to use.

To simplify the problem to get at the root of the issue. If I could understand the best method to finding the formula for the output current  in the circuit below, then i believe i should be able to apply the same method to the circuit above (where V1 is the same 10V peak to peak, 1kHz triangle wave)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7zn9p.png)</sup>

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you doing this as an instructional exercise, or do you really want to know?  A working engineer's solution to this would generally be "simulate it and see".

Comment: Is there some `device` that you need to characterize that is sitting where you've placed \$C_3\$ and \$R_3\$ with some surrounding fixture and cabling parasitics and you want to somehow apply a signal (which you have decided for currently unstated reasons is best done with a triangle, but possibly to expose the `device` to a range of voltages changing in two directions for an I-V curve that may not be the same both directions of voltage change) and that's what this is all about? Or what, exactly? It's an unusual form of question.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. Yes I am looking to characterize the device composed of C3 and R3. I need a formula specifically because the current that passed through R5 actually goes into an inverting op amp with a virtual ground. The signal is then amplified and passed into an ADC. We then need to determine the values for C3 and R3 and report the data. Unfortunately, we are required to use a triangle wave as the input regardless of whether or not that's the most ideal waveform to use.

Comment: @Noahwar97 Thanks. I nailed what was going on. But you really should have said so at the outset rather than allowing others to founder on this question. And I now think you need to write a lot more. I do note the addition about 8 hrs ago. But that's not what I mean. This is your issue. And I think you will get out from answers what you put into your question. I have my thoughts but I won't suggest what to add. You know the situation better than anyone and can work that out better than I can. What's here isn't enough for me. But that may just be me.

Answer (score 3):

I see 3 general ways to solve this problem:

1. Time Domain. No working engineer would attempt this. Maybe a professor would try this. You would need to solve the positive and negative ramps separately; the peaks are non-linear discontinuities.
2. Frequency domain with a Fourier series as you described. Of course, it will never be exact, but once you have the equation, you can replicate out to 100 harmonics easily.
3. Simulation.

So, what would engineers do before simulators? They would build it and make careful measurements. Or, simplify the circuit by deciding which parasitics are negligible.

Answer (score 2):

In electrical engineering, the study of an electrical network powered by a voltage varying over time is done using the Laplace transform of the applied electromotive force and of the electrical network itself. In the following photo I have written two different ways of mathematically representing the same signal. Once the transfer function of the network W(s) and the Laplace transform of the input signal Vi(s) of the bipolar triangular wave are known, we have the Laplace transform of the output signal Vo(s)=W(s )Vi(s). Once this is done, we need to anti-transform according to Laplace to obtain the output signal as a function of time.

[image]